# FactoryGirl child's after(:create) callback not run when parent's is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have something like the following:

```
# spec/factories/card.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do |f|
    first_name 'First Name'
    [...]
    emails { [ build(:email, :active) ] }
  end
end
```

I'm using `build` for emails so I don't get an error as email `belongs_to :card`.

```
# spec/factories/email.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :email do |f|
    address 'test@test.com'
  end

  trait :active do
    after(:create) do |email|
      email.active = true
      email.save
    end
  end
end
```

My email model:

```
# app/models/email.rb
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  before_save :set_confirm_key

  def set_confirm_key
    if address_changed?
      self.confirm_key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(15)
      self.active = false
      return
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that I have the `before_save` callback on my email model which sets active to false and if I do `FactoryGirl.create(:card)` the after(:create) hook doesn't get called in the email factory so I'm always getting inactive emails.

Comment: Please show your before_save callback.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you are not creating the email within factory girl. FactoryGirl builds it, so the `after(:create)` doesn't get called. The email gets saved when the parent is, out of FactoryGirl.

I would try an alternative approach:

```
factory :card do
  after(:create) do |card, evaluator|
    create_list(:email, 1, card: card, :active)
  end
end
```

I believe that will work.

Comment: I understand your explanation of why the callback isn't executed but the problem is that I have a validator on the card model which looks for at least an email, so I can't add the emails after the card's creation.

Comment: It doesn't have an easy solution. You cannot create a card without an email, and you cannot create an email without a card, plus you have an after save in the email model. I don't think you can bypass that within FactoryGirl. It seems to me that you need to write a before callback in your specs that resets the email's active field.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that. I wasted too much time with this chasing my tail around in circles.